# Integrating center of mass coordinates for two radial functions

Tags: classical-mechanics, vectors, integration

I have what is probably a trivial question but I am too embarrassed to ask my colleagues.

I have a function which only depends on the radial coordinate, $\rho(\vec{r})=\rho(r)$, which I know the functional form. One example is,
$$\rho(r)=\frac{\alpha}{1+e^{\beta(r-R)}},$$
where $\alpha,\beta,R$ are real, positive constants. Another example is $$\rho(r)=\frac{1}{r}\left(e^{-\alpha r}+e^{-\beta r}\right).$$

The quantity I want to calculate is defined as:

$$P(\vec{r})=\int \,\mathrm d^3\vec{R}~\rho\left(\vec{R}+\frac{\vec{r}}{2}\right)\rho\left(\vec{R}-\frac{\vec{r}}{2}\right)$$

but in reality I just want $P(r)$.

Going through the motions how I would think to do this, I would want to evaluate something like

$$P(r)=\int \text{sin}(\theta_R) R^2 \,\mathrm dR \,\mathrm d\theta_R \,\mathrm d\phi_R~\rho\left(\vert\vec{R}+\frac{\vec{r}}{2}\vert\right)\rho\left(\vert\vec{R}-\frac{\vec{r}}{2}\vert\right)$$

but

$$\vert\vec{R}\pm \frac{\vec{r}}{2}\vert=\sqrt{R^2+r^2 \pm 2rR(\text{sin}(\theta_r)\text{sin}(\theta_R)\text{cos}(\phi_r-\phi_R)+\text{cos}(\theta_r)\text{cos}(\theta_R))}$$

which is terribly complicated.

What am I missing, I think this should be very simple?

Comment: You're going to need some $\theta$-dependence, due to the fact that the two $\rho$ functions centered in different places violate spherical symmetry.

Comment: It might be easier to address this question if you included the functional form of $\rho$, more than just "ratio of polynomial and exponential".

Comment: @KyleKanos, I have added two example functions.

Answer (score 1):

So, you've basically got two "charges" which each produce some kind of "field", $\rho$. You're placing them in space with separation $r$, and you want to calculate the integral over all of space of the product between the two fields? This sounds like a good problem for cylindrical coordinates. We'll use $s$ as the radial cylindrical coordinate, since $r$ is already being used.

So, let's place the charges on the $z$ axis, with one at $z=\frac{r}{2}$ and the other at $z=-\frac{r}{2}$. Since $\rho$ only takes positive arguments, let's replace it with $\gamma$ so that $\rho(r)=\gamma(r^2)$. Then:

$$
P(r) = 2\pi\int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_0^\infty \gamma(x_1)\gamma(x_2)s ds dz
$$

Where $x_1=s^2+(z-\frac{r}{2})^2$ and $x_2=s^2+(z+\frac{r}{2})^2$.

Using reflectional symmetry ($z\to-z$), we can get:

$$
P(r) = 4\pi\int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty \gamma(x_1)\gamma(x_2)s ds dz
$$

The direction you go from here will depend on the exact nature of you function, $\rho(r)$. Where integrals are concerned, unfortunately, very few things are simple.

Comment: The evaluation of this integral is then fine (just done numerically). I am just confused about your coordinate transformation.

Comment: I assume you mean the transformation to get P(r)=4 pi ... It's not really a transformation. Since we have a reflectional symmetry across the plane of points that are equidistant between the two "charges", one only has to integrate on one side of the plane, and then multiply the answer by 2 to get the value for both sides.